# How do I enable highlight on the scroll bar displayihng the occurences of a search result in VIM?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When searching for a pattern within file/files in vim, I will like to show the match on the right hand scroll bar, so that I know the locations of the matches within the file and I could simply scroll with my mouse to the match location (similar to visual studio). Any advice on how to do this will be much appreciated.

I tried to google search on this, but answers are normally related to showing the search results at the bottom panel, but this is not what I am looking for.

The expected result should show highlights on the scroll bar on the right.

Comment: There is no scroll bar in Vim by default. Share your `.vimrc` doc.

Comment: Dear uprego, thanks for your reply. Indeed, I was thinking of using this project https://github.com/lornix/vim-scrollbar to add in the scroll bar, but not sure how could add in the search results on top of this scroll bar..

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal, Vim does not provide a scrollbar (there is `:set ruler` and the *statusline* to provide orientation). In graphical GVIM, the default scrollbars provided by the operating system / window manager are used.

To give you orientation for searches, recent Vim 8.1 versions can give *search statistics* (e.g. `[1/5]`), enabled via `:set shortmess-=S`. Plugins like my [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) can give you much more detailed information:

> ```
> 1 match after cursor in this line, 8 following, 2 in previous lines; ~
> total 10 within 11,42 for /\<SearchPosition\>/ ~
> ```